# neural networks and optimization problems in general

Tags: machine-learning, optimization

Neural networks are efficient at solving optimization problems.
The topic of optimization problems is divided into linear and nonlinear problems and in linear and nonlinear conditions. I just wonder how a network will be categorized accordingly.
For example, how do we set conditions? Do these terms fit anyway?

Comment: "Neural networks are efficient at solving optimization problems." really? how so

Comment: what else do they do?

Comment: usually they are used as a function approximator as part of a supervised or unsupervised learning model. i've read one or two papers experimenting on using neural networks to solve combinatorial optimization problems, but it's not really their main use case.

Comment: I think as a NN is modelled by optimizing its parameters, it is itself an optimization problem: You design it such that it solves a problem as best as possible.

Comment: yes, *training* an nn requires optimizing it's parameters, but that is carried out by a separate optimization algorithm -- usually a SGD variant. the network itself has nothing to do with the optimization algorithm used. are you asking about the optimizations *problem* at hand in this question?